# Laravel: clicking label does not set checkbox

Tags: checkbox, laravel, formbuilder

I'm using Laravel's form builder to generate a login form.  This seems really simple, but it's not working.  I'm trying to create a label for my checkbox which can be clicked to set/unset the checkbox.  Currently, clicking the label does nothing.  Here's my code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/account/login', 'role' => 'form')) }}
    {{ Form::token() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address', array('class' => 'sr-only')) }}
        {{ Form::text('email', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email Address')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'sr-only')) }}
        {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
    <a href="#forgotpassword" class="btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right">Forgot password?</button></a><br>
    {{ Form::checkbox('remember') }}
    {{ Form::label('remember', 'Remember me') }}
{{ Form:: close() }}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm probably missing something obvious.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe label elements link to `id` property not `name` property. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)
You need to create an `ìd` form the checkbox element.

You can try something like

`{{ Form::checkbox('remember', 1, null, ['id'=>'remember', 'class' => 'className']) }}`

This should work.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this was indeed the issue.  However, it's worth noting that Laravel's documentation says:  

"Note: After creating a label, any form element you create with a name matching the label name will automatically receive an ID matching the label name as well."

My problem was assuming this would still hold true even if the label is created AFTER the form element.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if the label is before the input element, the id tag will be automatically created.
But not, if the label comes after. So you need to add the id tag manually.